# Importing jquery in Angular6 : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, angular, angular6

I am trying to use `jquery@1.9.1` in my angular6 project.

1. I ran :

`npm install jquery@1.9.1 --save`

`npm install @types/jquery --save`

2. Added :

`"node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js"` into the `scripts` field of my `angular.json`

3. But when I put :

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

In my ts file I still get the error :

> ERROR in ./src/app/shared/functions/rendering.function.ts Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'C:...'

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Instead of impoting use **declare var $** in componnent

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please follow the [link](https://therichpost.com/how-to-run-jquery-in-angular-6) this might help, I thing don't need `@types/jquery`.

Comment: Following the steps yields : error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.

Comment: stupid jquery 1.9.1 had to upgrade to jquery 3 fortunately the old code that I'm working with is still working with it.

Comment: @Wicelo `npm install jquery` it's always reference latest version, in your case you need to find dependent version of `@types/jquery`. I was like you can understand that basic so I did not mentioned